# No air lock activity

Tags: fermentation

I am brewing a Black Rock..."Miners Stout" .  and it's been nearly a week in the fermenter with none to very little movement in the airlock. !
Seems odd as to all the other stouts that I have brewed.
Would this mean a faulty beer mix ?  the fermenter is sealed as for using vasaline 
around the thread and rubber seal...plus the rubber bung and the end of the airlock.
Temp; has been at 24c .  (as on a heat pad).
OG= 1055.
There is a thin line of Krausen around fermenter.
Your thoughts would be welcome.
From ...Darkest-porter

Comment: Did you take a gravity reading after a week?  Airlock movement is not reliable enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, No I have not, But will now do a gravity reading as you mentioned.  I will get back to you.........

Comment: OK..been out and the gravity reads as...1011 .

Comment: Just to say with all this brewing, I find it very interesting in that often no two brews are the same, it keeps you on your toes. The airlock does move about 3mm then settles then again and so forth...say at 30-40 second intervals .

Comment: Do you have a gravity reading from the end of your brew? If not, you'll want to give it a little more time then read again. If these values are decreasing, then you're getting fermentation. If not repitch your yeast.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your yeast is bad, it is too cold or it might just be a leak that you are not aware of.

Take a gravity reading to know if your yeast is working or not.

Comment: That was my thought as well. Maybe the wort was too hot when he added the yeast.